# Visual Studio Tools for Office breaks VB6

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vba, .net-3.5, vsto, office-2003

> **UPDATE 3:**
>
> This happens when I have saved the vb6
>   script, close word, start word, then
>   run the template as you would normally
>   run a template, i.e. strTemplate
>   becomes Normal.doc.  Then as soon as I
>   go back to the original template which
>   has not been saved through vsto, that
>   goes back to having Letter.doc in the
>   variable strTemplate...

**UPDATE 2:**

In my startup script, I have a line as follows:

```
strTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
```

In the original template which is named Letter.dot, strTemplate = Letter.dot.

But for some reason, in the new vsto template which was based on the original Letter.dot template, the same line above becomes Normal.dot, which is causing problems, even thought the new template is still named Letter.dot.

I tried to manually code in

```
strAttTemplate = "Letter.dot"
```

and the script gets to the next stage, but then it starts complaining about something else.

So my question is, the original template has strTemplate = Letter.dot, but why does this change to strTemplate = Normal.dot after running the template through vsto?

**UPDATE 1:**

After running through a debug for both versions of the template, i.e. the original non vsto template, and the new vsto template, I have found out that the original does not have any document properties, but the vsto template has 2 document properties.  But that does not seem to be a problem.

It seems that the problem has something to do with the vsto template has normal.dot attached to it, whereas the original non vsto template does not have normal.dot attached to it.

Is it possible to remove attached normal.dot from the new template?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to create a Word 2003 Template project.  I select the "use existing template" option which already has some vb6 macro scripting in the background.  For some reason, when I save the Visual Studio project, the vb6 scripting stops working.

the old vb6 script runs straight away when the template opens in word, but when i simply use the template in vs2008 without adding extra functionality and save the project and build the project, when i try to open the template in word, the old startup script does not work.

Why is this happening?

Comment: VBA is not VB6.  This is improperly tagged.

Comment: What code isn't running? It wouldn't be the AUTORUN macro, would it. I seem to recall an issue at one point where the autorun macro simply doesn't get executed by Word under certain conditions. Being loaded in the VS dev IDE might be one of them.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 1:** in the original question.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 2**: in the original question.

Comment: Ok. Weird. It might be time to ask a different question. If you have a template that has existing VBA code it, would it make more sense to a) keep that template AS IS, and start a new project based on VSTO  or  B) if that's not possible, translate your VBA code to VB.net (shouldn't be too tough)  or  C) Avoid VSTO all together and just add the additional functionality in VBA. Personally, the thought of mixing VBA and .net code via VSTO is nasty. I had to do it with a project, and it lasted only as long as it took to convert the VSTO code.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 3:** in the original question.

Comment: @oshirowanen: If I'm reading this correctly, you are importing your existing template into VSTO, pushing run (so that VSTO does it's compilation stuff), then going to the /bin/debug or /bin/release folder and trying to open your letter.dot template as a template in Word. Is that correct?

Comment: @Otaku, Almost, I am importing the existing template into VSTO, building the project without adding any new controls or write any new code, so that VSTO does it's compilation stuff, then I open the newly generated Letter.dot file in the /bin/release folder from word as you would normally open a template to create a new document based on the selected template.

Comment: Just for clarification purposes, I don't have the stand alone VSTO application, I am creating a word 2003 template project from Visual Studio 2008 Pro, and instead of creating a new template, I use the "use existing file" option to select the existing Letter.dot template as a starting point.

Comment: Got it. Okay, two other quick questions: **1)** Do you have both Word 2003 and Word 2007 installed on your machine? and **2)** Is your version of Word 2003 "Professional" or higher? VSTO solutions won't run under "Standard" or below. I have tested in your exact environment using the 3 subroutines listed in my post below. When I nav to the /bin/release folder, I double-click the "letter.dot" and the `AutoNew` routine runs. When I right-click "letter.dot" and choose "Open" the `AutoOpen` routine runs. In both routines I have substituted the message box...*(see next)*

Comment: with `MsgBox "AutoNew. Attached template is: " & ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate` and `MsgBox "AutoOpen. Attached template is: " & ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate` and in both cases the `AttachedTemplate` is "letter.dot". So I think we're going to actually see your start up code to make any further progress here.

Comment: Answer for Q1: No we just have MS Word 2003, we do not have any other versions of Word or Office installed.

Comment: Answer for Q2: We have the full MS Office 2003 Professional, so yes, it's Word 2003 Professional

Comment: @oshirowanen: Okay, got it. It must be what's in the startup routine - can you post that code? Like I said, I've replicated everything you've said here and I'm not having a problem with it running for me. Will need to see your code to be able to try to troubleshoot any further.

Comment: @Otaku, the startup routine has about 3000 lines of vb6 script.  I think it would be too much to post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely scenario is that you have a routine called `AutoExec` in your Word 2003 .dot VBA. This will not execute when deployed as a VSTO template because it's not the type of add-in Word expects in order to run `AutoExec` (it expects either .wll files or .dot files in your STARTUP folder). The way around this for VSTO is to use `AutoOpen` instead which will execute the code in that sub routine when the template is opened as a VSTO add-in.

You can try these three in VBA (in Word, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to get to the Visual Basic Editor):

```
Sub AutoNew()
    MsgBox "AutoNew runs when creating a document from a template"
End Sub
Sub AutoOpen()
    MsgBox "AutoOpen runs when opening a template as a document"
End Sub
Sub AutoExec()
    MsgBox "AutoExec runs when loading an add-in (a global template)"
End Sub
```

The other scenario is you don't have your security settings set to "Low" on your development machine's Word security settings.

---

Regarding your update #2, this usually happens when you run VSTO in debug mode (F5 instead of compiling and running it Ctrl + F5). Can you confirm how you are running it? If it is neither one of those, is it still normal.dot when you deploy it to a test machine?

Finally, if you could post your full startup script, that would be helpful in determining where the issue may truly lie.

Comment: Doh. AutoExec and AutoOpen. That's what I meant<g>. Hardly ever use that stuff anymore.

Comment: @drventure: unfortunately I'm still stuck in that world. or fortunately if I get the bounty :)

Comment: I tried replacing the AutoExec with AutoOpen, but that stopped all templates from starting the startup script, even the templates which were not VSTO.  So I reversed the changes, and the old templates starting working again.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 1:** in the original question.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 2**: in the original question.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 3:** in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the 2003 template is creating a DOCX or a DOTX file, and NOT a DOCM or DOTM file? With 2003 and later, Macro code won't run when it's in a DOCX or DOTX file.

Comment: The file extention does not seem to change, are you saying that it's creating a dotx file, but showing an extention of .dot?

Comment: DOCX, DOTX did not start until some time after 2003.

Comment: Not sure why this answer got voted down. DOCX, DOTX, DOCM, and DOTM are all the newer Zipped XML format files that later versions of Office will save to. I believe they were introduced in Office 2003, but became mainstream in 2007. There's an addon pack for Office XP and 2000 to allow reading and writing those new formats in Office XP and 2000. As for saving a DOC in a DOCX, that won't happen unless you do something odd like save the DOCX file and they manually rename it as a DOC (and i've seen this happen before so don't discount it!)

Comment: Honestly, If I was creating a template and I wanted to use VBA (looks like Vb6 code, you can edit it within Word), then I'd skip the VS2008 Project template and just create a new word template and be on my way.

Comment: Just tried in VS2010, when I create a new Word Template project, it's creating a DOTX file which definitely won't run any macro code. I don't have VS2008 with the older VSTO installed anymore, so I can't check that particular combination. If it's creating a plain ol' DOT file, you should be good. Create the project, compile, then load the DOT file in WORD (right click OPEN, don't just dbl click the DOT file) and you should then be able to open the VBA macro editor and made sure all your macro stuff is there and runnable.

Comment: Ah, just looked a bit and you'd definitely need the Office Compatibility Pack to load DOTX files in Office 2003, so in all likelyhood, that template IS creating a normal DOT file. Still, couldn't hurt to check it.

Comment: It does not seem to be creating docx files.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 1:** in the original question.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 2**: in the original question.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 3:** in the original question.